# Returned non-zero exit status -1073741819

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

So I promise I searched but I don't see this return number anywhere.  I'm using Python to loop through a software at work in order to do the same thing multiple times to make it faster.  I can post some of the code but not all since its confidential.  But below its dying on shell=True.  I can manually run this same function in the software itself and from a command prompt but it won't let me run this script to loop it.  It worked before but now it doesn't.  I have checked all the input files and they work.  Any help would be appreciated.
current_directory = os.getcwd()

```
# Move so it can be locally run
os.chdir(vulcandir)
bcfflname = bcfflname.replace(vulcandir+'/', '')
bmfflname = bmfflname.replace(vulcandir+'/', '')
logflname = logflname.replace(vulcandir+'/', '')
with open(logflname, 'w') as logfl:
    # Use bcalc
    cmdout = subprocess.check_output('"'+' '.join(\
                       [vulcanbinpath+'/bcalc.exe'+'"',
                        '{}'.format(bmfflname),
                        '{}'.format(bcfflname)]),
                    shell=True)
    logfl.write('{}\n'.format(md5(bmfflname)))
# Go back to the current working directory
```

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) (the part highlighted in red): "Warning Using shell=True can be a security hazard. See the warning under [Frequently Used Arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for details." Maybe try it with `shell = False`